# UITableViewCellContentView width is always zero according to the autoresizing mask (only on iOS 7)

Tags: uitableview, ios7, autolayout, uipopovercontroller, autoresizingmask

I'm using the Auto Layout approach of dynamic cell height as described in [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746930/426227). This works so far. Now I'm presenting my `UITableView` in a `UIPopoverController` what also works. Now to the interesting part: I'm presenting this popover from different view controllers. On the first view controller everything works as expected. If I switch to second view controller, which also provides this popover, the popover is completely empty (even without separator line!) and I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a706fa0 H:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7a707760]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a707ba0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a707060 H:[UILabel:0x7a707760]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a707ba0 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a706970 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a707ba0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a707060 H:[UILabel:0x7a707760]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a707ba0 )>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Now we pay attention to this part:

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7a706970 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a707ba0(0)]>"
```

It says that the width of the `UITableViewCellContentView` is zero according to the autoresizing mask. But the same code work on another view controller before. And the popover should be independent of my settings in a view controller. I tried to replicate the behavior in another project but I can't. This also only appear on iOS 7. On iOS 8 everything is working fine. I also tried to go away from auto layout and then the content is displayed (but not in the way I want). The only option I can come up with is to go back to spring and struts ... If you want I could provide my code in C#, but I left it out to make the question more readable.

What could be the reason for this? Has anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After searching for a day for the reason it was the default mistake one could make. Because I had the controller before not in a popover the following line of code was still there:

```
myViewControllerInPopup.View.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

I had this on the view controller which instantiated the popover. Remove this line and everything work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

helper checker inspired by testing

```
extension UIView {
  func assertDoesNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(recurse: Bool = false) {
    if translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
      assertionFailure()
    }
    for view in subviews {
      if recurse {
        view.assertDoesNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(recurse: true)
      }
      if view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints {
        assertionFailure()
      }
    }
  }

}
```